# Can I do an optional LEFT JOIN in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, left-join

I'm selecting products from a database table. Currently the query is launched from Coldfusion, where I have an "optional LEFT JOIN" like so:

```
SELECT a.products
FROM artikelstammdaten a
  <cfif modul_aktiv("preorder", my_module) IS "true">
     LEFT JOIN...
  </cfif>
WHERE ...
```

**Question:**
Is it possible to do an optional LEFT JOIN in MySQL. I'm thinking something like this:

```
SELECT a.products
FROM artikelstammdaten a
    AND ( 
        ((param_preorder = 'false') "(1=2)" )
          OR LEFT JOIN ...  
        )
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT a.products
FROM artikelstammdaten a
LEFT JOIN [another_table] ON [your parameterized condition] AND [the real join condition]
(...)
```

The LEFT JOIN will be done, whatever your condition is, but if it is false, it won't bring back any record.

But you certainly can't emulate the `cfif` in pure SQL :)

Comment: So ON can be any criteria I want (such as parameter = true) and does not have to be related to the tables I want to join?

Comment: Indeed :) The `ON` condition can be anyone. Even `ON FALSE` :p

Comment: Are you certain that MySQL will do the LEFT JOIN even if *a condition that does not require the joined data* fails? I've been wondering about this for a while. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Although http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html leads me to believe that the LEFT JOIN is probably optimized away, some performance tests seem to indicate that you are correct: the query is *faster* when the join-independent condition is *true*. In other words, if the join-independent condition is false, *more* work is done, namely the nulling out of some columns. This is a disappointment...